# How do I pass a list to a function?

Tags: list, types, f#

I'm trying to create a function that accepts a list of cards and returns a list without a specific card in it. How do I pass a list of defined types to a function?

I passed a list to the function and it stated my types are not matching.

```
type Suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades
type Rank = Jack | Queen | King | Ace | Num of int
type Card = Rank * Suit
type Color = Red | Black
type Move = Discard of Card | Draw


let cards = [(Jack,Clubs); (Num(8),Spades)]
let c:Card = Jack, Clubs

let remove_card (cs, c:Card, e:string) = 
  cs
remove_card cards c "Err"
```

Expected list to return properly when calling function remove_card.
But, error is thrown:

This expression was expected to have type
    '('a -> 'b -> 'c) * Card * string'
but here has type
    '(Rank * Suit) list'

Answer (score 3):

It's because you've defined your `remove_card` function as a function that takes a single tupled parameter and returns a value, but you're calling it like a function that takes three parameters. To call `remove_card` the way you have it defined now you'd need to call it like `remove_card (cards, card, "Err")`, creating the three-argument tuple and calling the function with it.  I think what you probably meant to do was:

```ml
let remove_card cardList cardToRemove err = 
  cardList

remove_card cards c "Err"
```

i.e. creating a function with three arguments instead of a single tupled argument.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter syntax in F# is quite different from other common languages.

Your function - though looks like having 3 parameters - actually has only one parameter which is a tuple of 3 components.

So you have to call it like `remove_card (cards, c, "Err")`

However, in idiomatic F#, without special requirement, we often don’t use tuple for parameters. Instead, we use separated parameters to leverage [partial application](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/) when needed:

```
let remove_card cs (c:Card) (e:string) = ...
let remove_card_withFixedCards = remove_card cards
```